# Broken pipes in C -- pipe(), fork(), exec() program

Tags: linux, exec, fork, pipe

I need to write a simple program: There will be a Parent and a few programs [children] (started via `execl` in Parent). Children communicate to one another in this way: Child I sens to Parent number J, Parent sends a message (something like -- "there is a message to you") to J, J send to Parent number K etc. etc.

And there is a problem -- my program (tested by `strace` command) tries to send a message to child and there comes the broken pipe error.

I will be grateful if somebody looks through the code and tells me what's wrong:

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Arbiter zabawy w Losia
 *

 wersja: Alfa 3b
 początek edycji 25.01.2009
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "err.h"

pid_t pid;
FILE *a;

int main ()
{
    // my N players
    int N;
    N = 10;
    //write -- writing from parent to child 
    //read -- reading from child
    int rurka_write[N+1][2]; 
    int rurka_read[N+1][2];
    //initiation of N players
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        //tworze lacza
        if (pipe(rurka_write[i]) == -1)
            printf("wystapil blad przy rurce %d\n", i);
        if (pipe(rurka_read[i]) == -1)
            printf("wystapil blad przy rurce %d\n", i); 
    }
    for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        switch(pid = fork())
        {
            case -1: 
                printf("wystapil blad przy forkowaniu");
            case 0:
                printf("potomek numer %d\n", i);
                if (close(rurka_write[i][1]) == -1)
                    printf("zle zamykanie");
                if (close(rurka_read[i][0]) == -1)
                    printf("zle zamykanie");

                //closing useless descriptors
                int j;
                for(j = 1; j <= N; j++)
                {
                    if (j != i)
                    {
                        close(rurka_read[j][0]);
                        close(rurka_read[j][1]);
                        close(rurka_write[j][0]);
                        close(rurka_write[j][1]);
                    }
                }   

                char str_N[20];
                char str_i[20];
                char str_0[20];
                char str_1[20];

                sprintf(str_N, "%d", N);
                sprintf(str_i, "%d", i);
                sprintf(str_0, "%d", rurka_write[i][0]);
                sprintf(str_1, "%d", rurka_read[i][1]);

                printf("%d Executing execl\n", i);
                execl("./ucz", str_N, str_i, str_0, str_1, NULL);
                printf("execl executed\n");
//              execv("./ucz", str_N, str_i, str_0, str_1, NULL);
                //exit(0);
            default:
                //closing useless pipes
                if (close(rurka_read[i][1]) == -1)
                    printf("zle zamykanie rurki do czytania z potomkna\n");
                if (close(rurka_write[i][0]) == -1)
                    printf("zle zamykanie rurki do pisania do potomka\n");
        } //end of switch

    } //end of for
    //if I am in parent, I'm starting the game
    if (pid != 0)
//  delay(100);
    {
        printf("PLAY\n");
        int l = 1;
        while(l > 0)
        {
            printf("sending to player %d\n", l);
            a = fdopen(rurka_write[l][1], "w");
            printf("sending: Wake up");
            fprintf(a, "Wake up\n");
            printf("flushing");
            fflush(a);
            char k[20];
            printf("reading");
            read(rurka_read[l][0], k, 20);
            l = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your error along with your code.

Comment: I think there's a bug in your program: I think you mean to finish your case statements with 'break;'.

Comment: I really can't answer without seeing what "ucz" does with its parameters.
also, you should exit/abort after exec* (since exec isn't supposed to return unless an error occured, and it generally messes with your code flow)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that you do not end your cases with a `break` (as noted by strager), the main problem is the statement `l = k;`. Note that `k` is a `char[20]` and, when assigned to a `int`, you don't assign any of the contents of `k` to `l`. Instead `l` will contain (the value of) the pointer to the array. You will have to do something different here to get the value that is in the array; what exactly depends on that `ucz` sends back.

After fixing this and making my own `ucz`, the program seems to work without any problem. Of course, it might also be that there is another problem in your version of `ucz`.

Answer (score 0):

About ./ucz -- it takes 4 parameters -- 1st -- number of players, 2nd -- player number, 3rd -- number of descriptor to read from parent, 4th -- number of descriptor to write to parent.

Adding exit(0), return(0), break after exec (or in the end of "case: 0") doesn't help.